# Why doesn't Module.method_defined?(:method) work correctly?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to check if a method is defined in a module using `Module.method_defined?(:method)` and it is returning false it should be returing true.

```
module Something
  def self.another
    1
  end
end
```

`Something.methods` has 'another' listed but `Something.method_defined?(:another)` returns `false`.

Is this maybe not working because the method is defined on self? If this is the case is there another way to check if the method is defined on the module other than using `method_defined?`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To know whether the module has a module method, you can use respond_to? 
on the
module:

```
Something.respond_to?(another)
=> true
```

method_defined? will tell you whether INSTANCES of the class with the module included responds to the given method.

Comment: Perhaps I am reading this wrong, but shouldn't it be `Something.respond_to?(:another)` so `another` is a symbol. Otherwise wouldn't `another` cause an undefined error?

Answer (score 6):

Modules methods are defined in its **metaclass**. So you can also check for method inclusion with:

```
k = class << Something; self; end # Retrieves the metaclass
k.method_defined?(:another)  #=> true
```

You can read more about it in [*Understanding Ruby Metaclasses*](http://web.archive.org/web/20100410145014/http://vision-media.ca/resources/ruby/understanding-ruby-metaclasses).

Comment: The diagram on that site is confusing to say the least. What does it mean by the instance 'inheriting' the methods from the class? seems like wrong terminology to me. Also what does it mean by the arrow labeled `instance_eval` pointing to the metaclass? `instance_eval` evaluation does not happen on the metaclass, it happens on the instance - the only exception being the behaviour of `def` in an `instance_eval` which instead defines methods on the metaclass.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why the other answer go the checkmark. This is the way to actually do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding my version of the answer

Using the singleton_methods method:

```
module Something
  def self.another
  end
end

Something.singleton_methods.include?(:another) #=> true, with all parent modules
Something.singleton_methods(false).include?(:another) #=> true, will check only in the Something module
```