# How do I check if a module responds to a class method?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby, **not** Rails.

My Ruby app provides the ability to extend its functionality by loading user-defined modules. For the sake of simplicity, below is the structure of a valid module:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass < AppSuperClass
    def initialize
      puts "Hello"
    end
  end

  def self.create_class
    return MyClass.new
  end
end
```

As you can see, the module must implement a class that inherits from `AppSuperClass` and must implement a module method called `create_class`.

If the above module is in file `mymodule.rb` and I include it in another file like so:

`require 'mymodule'`

I need to check that `MyModule` responds to `MyModule.create_class`. For some reason, `MyModule.method_defined?(create_class)` and `MyModule.method_defined(:create_class)` both return `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're missing an `end` for the `def initialize` block so your `create_class` method is getting defined in the `MyClass` body - you should fix the indentation to make these kinds of errors more obvious.

After fixing this, you can use `MyModule.respond_to?(:create_class)`. The reason `method_defined?` doesn't work as expected with class methods is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1983860/2981429).

Answer (score 2):

As posted, your code does not work :

```
$ ruby -w m.rb 
m.rb:5: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 3
m.rb:10: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'class' at 2
m.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `create_class' for main:Object (NameError)
```

After changing `MyModule.method_defined?(create_class)`

to `MyModule.method_defined?(:create_class)` :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
false
t.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `method_defined' for MyModule:Module (NoMethodError)
```

What you probably want is`respond_to?`.

File `m.rb`

```
class AppSuperClass
end

module MyModule
  class MyClass < AppSuperClass
    def initialize
      puts "Hello"
    end
  end

  def self.create_class
    return MyClass.new
  end

  def mm
  end
end
```

File `t.rb`

```
require_relative 'm'

class MyClass
    include MyModule
end

puts "you can send create_class to MyModule because it's a singleton (class) method"
puts "MyModule.respond_to?(:create_class) => #{MyModule.respond_to?(:create_class)}"

puts 'mm is not a singleton method of MyModule'
puts "MyModule.respond_to?(:mm) => #{MyModule.respond_to?(:mm)}"

puts 'mm is an instance method of MyClass, cannot be sent to MyClass'
puts "MyClass.respond_to?(:mm) => #{MyClass.respond_to?(:mm)}"

puts 'mm is an instance method of MyClass, can be sent to an instance of MyClass'
puts "MyClass.new.respond_to?(:mm) => #{MyClass.new.respond_to?(:mm)}"

puts "instance methods of MyModule : #{MyModule.instance_methods}"

puts "MyModule.method_defined?(:create_class) => #{MyModule.method_defined?(:create_class)}"
puts "MyModule.method_defined?(:mm) => #{MyModule.method_defined?(:mm)}"

puts "singleton methods of MyModule : #{MyModule.singleton_methods}"

module MyModule
    class << self
        puts 'we are in the singleton class / eigenclass'
        puts "method_defined?(:create_class) => #{method_defined?(:create_class)}"
    end
end
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
you can send create_class to MyModule because it's a singleton (class) method
MyModule.respond_to?(:create_class) => true
mm is not a singleton method of MyModule
MyModule.respond_to?(:mm) => false
mm is an instance method of MyClass, cannot be sent to MyClass
MyClass.respond_to?(:mm) => false
mm is an instance method of MyClass, can be sent to an instance of MyClass
MyClass.new.respond_to?(:mm) => true
instance methods of MyModule : [:mm]
MyModule.method_defined?(:create_class) => false
MyModule.method_defined?(:mm) => true
singleton methods of MyModule : [:create_class]
we are in the singleton class / eigenclass
method_defined?(:create_class) => true
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. It's nicely demonstrated the different ways of interrogating an object. I corrected the indentation and missing `end` statement. They weren't part of the actual problem (that was a copy/paste error at midnight) but good spot.